# How can I boot without connecting the monitor and use the connected monitor later?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I am using "Nvidia" and I know how to boot without a monitor connected with the following command.

`sudo nvidia-xconfig --allow-empty-initial-configuration`

However, if you connect the monitor later, you can not see the screen. What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: This will be of no help at all, but I am just curious; /why/ do you want to start the machine without the monitor ?

Comment: If a computer is not main, I think it is natural. This is because several desktops are connected by a limited number of screens.